# Why does CruiseControl.NET's GIT source control block use "log -m" to get modifications?

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

We have a git repository with 2 branches, master and dev. New stuff does in dev. Fixes are done in master which then gets merged into dev.  CruiseControl.NET handles the building for us. We had a problem that the git source control block was listing modifications to files that hadn't changed. It seems this is because it uses git log with -m to detect changes.

Here are the steps we took:

1. On dev branch, make a single change.
2. Commit and push dev to the remote repository.
3. CruiseControl.Net then fetches the latest version, builds and releases this single change.
4. On the master branch, change another file.
5. Commit.
6. Merge master into dev.
7. Pushed dev to the remote repository.
8. CruiseControl.Net then fetches the latest version, builds and released both this and previous change!

In step 8, git log was run with the --name-only and -m options to detect modifications. -m  causes all files included in the merge to be listed, which included the file changed in step 1. But this file wasn't modified in step 4, so shouldn't be listed as a modification in step 8.

So why is -m used?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik -m was introduced to detect merge commits correctly.

See this change: https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/commit/a65380e7d302370cfcb6fa3905dba0ed1b731458